# c++ Change the value of a variable based on time

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, default-value

I have the following function in my C++, which I am tryig to use to update the information displayed on part of a GUI:

```
void store::updateHeader(){
    ...
    strstart = &newHeaderMsg.headerText[0];
    *strstart = 'D';
    const char* originalStrStartValue = strstart;
    double timeWarningStarted = SimulationTime::Instance()->getSimulationTime();

    if(warningSelect == 1){
        timer->begin();
        ...
        warningTimeout = 15; // time in seconds
        double timeWarningDisplayed = SimulationTime::Instance()->getSimulationTime();

        if(timerStarted){
            *strstart = 'R';
            if(timeWarningDisplayed >= (timeWarningStarted + warningTimeout)){
                *strstart = *originalStrStartValue;
            }
        } else {
            *strstart = originalStrStartValue;
        }
    } else {
    *strstart = originalStrStartValue;
    }
}
```

Basically, the logic of the function is:

1. Create a variable that will hold the memory location of the first element of an array (the array `newHeaderMsg.headerText[]`). The variable is called `strstart`.
2. Set the memory location of `strstart` equal to 'D'
3. Get the current system time, and pass its value to the variable `timeWarningStarted`.
4. If a particular selection is made on the GUI (i.e. `warningSelect` is set to `1`, begin a timer, and set the `warningTimeout` variable to 15 (15 seconds). Then get the current system time, and set its value to the variable `timeWarningDisplayed`.
5. If the timer has started, set variable at the memory location of the first element in the array (i.e. the memory location of `strstart`) to 'R'.
6. Check whether the `timeWarningDisplayed` variable is greater than or equal to the sum of `timeWarningStarted` and `warningTimeout` (if it is, then the warning has been displayed for the intended length of time)
7. If `timeWarningDisplayed` is greater than or equal to the sum of `timeWarningStarted` and `warningTimeout`, then set the value of `*strstart` to the value of `originalStrStartValue`, i.e. set it back to 'D'.
8. Otherwise, if `warningSelect` is something other than '1', set the value of `*strstart` to the value of `originalStrStartValue`, i.e. set it back to 'D'.

The issue that I'm having is trying to set the value of the variable `originalStrStartValue`. If I run the program with the code as it is above, then despite having declared `originalStrStartValue` with `const`, because I chage the value of the variable it is pointing to, its value also changes.

If I try to set it to the memory location of `strstart` instead, i.e.

```
const char* originalStrStartValue = *strstart;
```

then I get the compile error:

> Error: a value of type "char" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "const char * "

So my question is, how can I create a 'default' value for a variable at a particular memory location in a function, then in the same function, change the value of that variable when a particular condition is true, but automatically revert back to the default value the moment that condition is no longer true?

Comment: What's unclear from the compiler error message actually? Did you rather mean to write `const char* originalStrStartValue = strstart;`?

Comment: @scohe001 it does, you're right, my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you get is expected and clear. You cannot convert char to char pointer as those two types are completely unrelated.

As I understand, you only want to change first character of character array. Why don't you declare `originalStrStartValue` as `char` (or `const char`) and then revert to that value if needed?

```
    const char originalStrStartValue = *strStart;
    ...
    *strStart = originalStrStartValue
```